# tf.nn.in_top_k gives error and I don't know why: NotFoundError: Could not find valid device for node. Node:{{node InTopKV2}}

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I am trying to understand what top k categorical accuracy means, so I looked at the source code, and I found out it used nn.in_top_k.
I tried to experiment with this function but got only error message:

```
NotFoundError: Could not find valid device for node.
Node:{{node InTopKV2}}
All kernels registered for op InTopKV2 :
  device='XLA_GPU'; T in [DT_INT32, DT_INT64]
  device='XLA_CPU'; T in [DT_INT32, DT_INT64]
  device='XLA_GPU_JIT'; T in [DT_INT32, DT_INT64]
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_INT64]
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_INT32]
  device='XLA_CPU_JIT'; T in [DT_INT32, DT_INT64]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_INT64]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_INT32]
 [Op:InTopKV2]
```

My original code that produced this error:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import nn

y_true = [[0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0]]
y_pred = [[0.1, 0.9, 0.8], [0.05, 0.95, 0]]

y_pred=tf.convert_to_tensor(y_pred, dtype=tf.float32)
y_true = tf.convert_to_tensor([2,1], dtype=tf.int32)


print(nn.in_top_k(y_pred, y_true, k=3))
```

I googled and it could be input data type problem, but also I set type according to this [website](https://docs.w3cub.com/tensorflow%7Epython/tf/nn/in_top_k/) which are float32 and int32, so I thought they should be correct. Any help on why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce error in Tensorflow Version 2.x using below code

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
from tensorflow import nn

y_true = [[0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0]]
y_pred = [[0.1, 0.9, 0.8], [0.05, 0.95, 0]]

y_pred=tf.convert_to_tensor(y_pred, dtype=tf.float32)
y_true = tf.convert_to_tensor([2,1], dtype=tf.int32)

out=nn.in_top_k(y_pred, y_true, k=3)
```

Output:

```
2.1.0
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotFoundError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-7ecc0c53e0ee> in <module>()
     10 y_true = tf.convert_to_tensor([2,1], dtype=tf.int32)
     11 
---> 12 out=nn.in_top_k(y_pred, y_true, k=3)

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

NotFoundError: Could not find valid device for node.
Node:{{node InTopKV2}}
All kernels registered for op InTopKV2 :
  device='XLA_GPU'; T in [DT_INT32, DT_INT64]
  device='XLA_CPU'; T in [DT_INT32, DT_INT64]
  device='XLA_CPU_JIT'; T in [DT_INT32, DT_INT64]
  device='XLA_GPU_JIT'; T in [DT_INT32, DT_INT64]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_INT64]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_INT32]
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_INT64]
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_INT32]
 [Op:InTopKV2]
```

To fix this error, you have to shift arguments positions in `in_top_k`. Please refer working code in below

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
from tensorflow import nn

y_true = [[0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0]]
y_pred = [[0.1, 0.9, 0.8], [0.05, 0.95, 0]]

y_pred=tf.convert_to_tensor(y_pred, dtype=tf.float32)
y_true = tf.convert_to_tensor([2,1], dtype=tf.int32)

print(nn.in_top_k(y_true, y_pred,  k=3))
```

Output:

```
2.1.0
tf.Tensor([ True  True], shape=(2,), dtype=bool)
```

To accomplish current task in TF 2.3.0, you can use [tf.math.in_top_k](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/in_top_k)

```
print(tf.math.in_top_k(y_true, y_pred,  k=3)) # tf.Tensor([ True  True], shape=(2,), dtype=bool)
```

You can refer source code for this [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.3.0/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py#L5611-L5614)